# Как убрать определенный символ из строки?

Tags: python, строки

Как называется команда, которая может убрать определённый символ из строки?
К примеру, из строки "1\n" мне нужно убрать '\n'

Comment: По мотивам присутствовавшего ранее ответа: какая у вас реальная задача? Вам нужно именно убрать переносы строк в конце, или это просто пример от балды и символ может быть любым? Убираемый символ обязательно в конце или может быть в начале и середине строки? Если он может быть в середине, нужно ли его оттуда убирать?

Comment: Удаляем все пробельные символы справа - [`print("1\n".rstrip())`](https://ideone.com/VFVesT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убрать из строки все вхождения какого-то символа можно так:

```
str.replace(symbol, "")
```

Например:

```
new_str = "1\n\n234\n56\n".replace("\n", "")  // "123456"
```

Если нужно убрать только первое вхождение символа, добавьте третий параметр:

```
new_str = "1\n\n234\n56\n".replace("\n", "", 1)  // "1\n234\n56\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str_ = "--1--2-3--"

s = str_.lstrip('-')  # 1--2-3--
s = str_.rstrip('-')  # --1--2-3
s = str_.strip('-')  # 1--2-3

s = str_.replace('-', '')  # 123

tr = {ord(c): '' for c in ['-', ]}
s = str.translate(str_, tr)  # 123

s = ''.join(c for c in str_ if c != '-')  # 123
s = ''.join(str_.split('-'))  # 123

s = str_.split('-', 2)[2]  # 1--2-3--
s = str_.rsplit('--', 1)[0]  # --1--2-3
```

Comment: можно `str_.translate(tr)` вместо klass.method(obj, *args) синтаксиса. И если мы все причастные методы упоминаем, то можно ещё `str_.partition('-')[::2]` (результат кортеж).  А для примера из вопроса, можно `str_.splitlines()` метод использовать (результат список). Для более сложных критериев можно регулярные выражения использовать (к примеру, убрать дефисы в конце строк перед \n).